# Making pie chart's borders smoother with ggplot on R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I performed a script to obtain a pie/donut chart in R with ggplot.

Here my script

```
    ggplot(dat1, aes(x = treatment, y = data, fill = group, color = treatment)) +
  geom_col(size=.8) +
  scale_color_manual(values=c("black", "gold3")) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette="Paired") +
  coord_polar("y") +
  geom_text(aes(label = data), position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5), size =4, fontface="bold") +
  theme_void() +
  ggtitle ("Title") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size = 25))
```

It worked exactly as I wanted, except that the borders is quite crappy, as you can see in the figure, it seems free hand drawn.

[image: chart borders]

Is there any way to make the borders more precise and smooth, like a perfect circle?

Thank you for your always invaluable help and insights.

Comment: Hi @user18463598, could you please provide reproducible data using `dput(dat1)` so that we can help you?

Comment: `structure(list(group = c("A", "B", "C ", "D", "E", "F", "G ", "H ", "I ", "K ", "L ", "J ", A", "B", "C ", "D", "E", "F", "G ", "H ", "I ", "K ", "L ", "J "), treatment = c("q", "q", "q", "q", "q", "q", "q", "q", "q", "q", "q", "q", "w", "w", "w", "w", "w", "w", "w", "w", "w", "w", "w", "w"), data = c(60, 40, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 70, 10, 0, 0, 5, 5., 1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 1), class = "data.frame")` 

Thank you very much

Comment: I'm trying out your code but cant get the same thing to happen - creates perfectly smooth lines when I export using `ggsave` or RStudio>'Export to pdf'. It might be something to do with how you're saving it - what process are you using for that?

Comment: I tried RStudio>'Export to pdf', and it works well. However, I would export it as metafile, since I want to separate the image in his components then, to do some additional work in powerpoint, and if I export it as metafile, I get this crappy effect.

Comment: would suggest using `ggsave` to make it an `svg` file then - that seems to be smoothest :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a potentially helpful way of getting an editable version, you could try the `export` package (only on GitHub at the moment) which gives you a smooth editable vector image in a powerpoint slide:

```r
# devtools::install_github("tomwenseleers/export")
library(ggplot2)

df <- tibble::tribble(
  ~group, ~treatment, ~data,
     "A",        "q",    60,
     "B",        "q",    40,
     "C",        "q",     0,
     "D",        "q",     0,
     "E",        "q",     0,
     "F",        "q",     0,
     "G",        "q",     0,
     "H",        "q",     0,
     "I",        "q",     0,
     "K",        "q",     0,
     "L",        "q",     0,
     "J",        "q",     0,
     "A",        "w",    70,
     "B",        "w",    10,
     "C",        "w",     0,
     "D",        "w",     0,
     "E",        "w",     5,
     "F",        "w",     5,
     "G",        "w",     1,
     "H",        "w",     1,
     "I",        "w",     1,
     "K",        "w",     1,
     "L",        "w",     5,
     "J",        "w",     1
  )


g <- ggplot(df, aes(x = treatment, y = data, fill = group, color = treatment)) +
  geom_col(size=.8) +
  scale_color_manual(values=c("black", "gold3")) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette="Paired") +
  coord_polar("y") +
  geom_text(aes(label = data), position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5), size =4, fontface="bold") +
  theme_void() +
  ggtitle ("Title") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size = 25))

export::graph2ppt(g, "output_graph.pptx")
#> Exported graph as output_graph.pptx
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you very much Andy, this tip is awfully helpful!!!

Answer (score 1):

I only add this as an answer to share the images. This isn't due to ggplot2 output. No matter how big or small I exported the image, I did not get the output to reflect what you have.

What circumstances led you to the image you have? Was it a screenshot in RStudio? Was it an exported image? Was it in R Markdown?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your very kind help. My output is from the R Studio graphic device. I tried to export it both as metafile or bitmap, but still have the same problem. Thank you again.

Comment: Ah, well that is part of what the problem is! You aren't going to get very good output with either file type. Have you considered png or the like? SVG offers great clarity, but MS Office isn't all that SVG-friendly anymore.